# Error with if and foreach

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

i used if condition in foreach but the if condition is only working for first value.

```
foreach ($my1 as $my2) {
    if ($subsubcategory == $my2){
        $selected = "selected";
    } else {
    }
    echo ' <a href="#"class="selectable '.$selected.'"><i class="box"></i>'.$my2.'</a>';}
}
```

Only for first value if condition is false and for all other values it is true . So does anyone here has any idea about this problem.

Comment: wheres $subcategory set? what are the values for $my?

Comment: @EvilEpidemic Do they matter?

Comment: makes it a more complete example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `$selected` to the empty string in the `else` clause. Otherwise, it will persist from the previous iteration:

```
foreach ($my1 as $my2) {
    if ($subsubcategory == $my2){
        $selected = "selected";
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    echo ' <a href="#"class="selectable '.$selected.'"><i class="box"></i>'.$my2.'</a>';}
}
```

Comment: Or simply define `$selected=''` at start of the loop, removing else condition.